# $5$ consecutive lotto numbers, why $44!/42!$?

Tags: combinatorics

I read about the  probability of $5$ consecutive lotto numbers. $6$ numbers are drawn and there are $49$ numbers. It said that there are $44!/42!$ possibilities to get $5$ consecutive numbers. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: This assumes we understand what a lotto is. Try to give an explanation. “It said…” What said? Some drunk guy at the bar, or a website, or a book, or …

Comment: There are 49 balls with numbers. You draw 6 numbers, you cant draw the same number and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: That is $43 \times 44$.  Consider the smallest of the five consecutive and the non-consecutive number.  Then worry about what happens if the consecutive numbers are $1,2,3,4,5$ or $45,46,47,48,49$

Comment: I think I get it a little bit now. I understand it with 2*42 + 43*42. I don't understand why they wrote 44!/(42!*1!*1!) tho, is there a formula for that? Or why factorial at all?

Comment: They wrote 44!/(43!*1!) for 6 consecutive numbers. I have no idea why they wrote 1!, I feel like there has to be a formula I don't know about

Comment: There are $44$ ways to have six consecutive numbers since there are $44$ possible lowest numbers.  If you think of the six consecutive numbers as a block, there are a total of $43 + 1 = 44$ objects to permute, the block and the other $43$ numbers.  There are $\binom{44}{1} = \frac{44!}{1!43!}$ ways to select the position of the block of six consecutive numbers.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the stated answer is the number of ways of selecting *exactly* five consecutive lotto numbers when six numbers are drawn from the set of the first $49$ positive integers.

Comment: You should also clarify that the $49$ numbers are the integers $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 49$.

Comment: Henry is correct to point out that the answer is equivalent to $44 \cdot 43$.  However, the reason for the answer is that they want exactly five consecutive numbers to be selected not that they are concerned about the first five numbers and last five numbers.